# cant duplicate a value from database on php

Tags: php

i am making a dynamic form right now, duplicating the form is easy, but there is one textfield where the value is from the database, the problem is, the value from the database cant be duplicated. the point is im trying to duplicate a value in php, here is the problem, and is there anyway to insert a data into database using `<label>` ? because duplicating the value using `<label>` is a succsed

[image]

here is my code.

```
<?php
include 'config/db_connect.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
for($i = 0; $i <= count($_POST['kode'])-1;$i++){
$selectidmax =mysqli_query($con, "SELECT max(jenis) as maxjenis FROM t_produk WHERE jenis LIKE 'SS%'");
$hslidmax=mysqli_fetch_array($selectidmax);
$idmax=$hslidmax['maxjenis'];
$nourut = (int) substr($idmax, 2,3);
$nourut++;
$IDbaru = "SS" . sprintf("%03s", $nourut);
$kodep = $_POST['kode'][$i];
$kodeproduk = $_POST['kp'][$i];
$produk = $_POST['produk'][$i];
$bunga = $_POST['bunga'][$i];
$ket = $_POST['ket'][$i];

$query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO t_produk(kode_cu,jenis,kode_produk,produk,bunga,keterangan)
    VALUES (
    '$kodep',
    '$IDbaru',
    '$kodeproduk',
    '$produk',
    '$bunga',
    '$ket') 
    ");
}

    if($query){
        header("location:home_cu.php");
    }else{
        echo "gagal" . mysqli_error($con);
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form Simpanan Saham</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="w3-bar w3-black">
  <a href="home_cu.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Home</a>
  <a href="view_cu.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Menu Data Cu</a>
  <a href="home_kebijakan.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Menu Data Kebijakan</a>
  <a href="data_modifikasi.php" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">Menu Data Modifikasi</a>
</div>
<br>
<div class="container">
        <form action="form_saham.php" method="post">
                <h1 class="text-center">Produk Pinjaman</h1>
                <div class="form-content">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p><button type="button" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-primary">Add More</button></p>
                        <br/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row group">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <?php 
include 'config/db_connect.php';
$kode = $_GET['kode_cu'];
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM t_cu WHERE kode_cu = '$kode'");
while ($hasil = mysqli_fetch_array($query) ) {
?>
                            <label>Kode Produk :</label>
                            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $hasil['kode_cu']?>" name="kode[]" class="form-control">
                            <input type="text" name="kp[]" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Produk</label>
                            <input type="text" name="produk[]" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Bunga</label>
                            <input type="text" name="bunga[]" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Keterangan</label>
                            <textarea name="ket[]" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btnRemove">Remove</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.multifield.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('.form-content').multifield({
            section: '.group',
            btnAdd:'#btnAdd',
            btnRemove:'.btnRemove',
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You know your queries are vulnerable to SQL injection?

Comment: yes, i will change it into prepared statement, thank you

Answer (score -1):

Ok, i found the question by myself, i just move the `<input type="text" value="<?php echo $hasil['kode_cu']?>" name="kode[]" class="form-control">` to the top, so this textfield won't get duplicated, and then in the database value i changed the `'$kodep',` into `(SELECT kode_cu FROM t_cu WHERE kode_cu = '$kodep'),` Thank you for everyone who tries to help